# Is hot reload possible in Glassfish at least for development purposes?

Tags: glassfish

I had this question ever since I learnt about Erlang and it's possibility for hot replacements of separate modules and even functions on a production server.

We are developing a project in Java for Glassfish 2.1. It's basically an .ear file consisting of a bunch of .war modules.

So, every time, I make a minor change in the code of one of the modules, in order to check that change I have to redeploy the whole ear on my development server. Is that really how it's supposed to work?

Basically we have several levels of replacement - are they even possible?

- The war module. Happens during a big number of commits by several developers. Is it possible to replace just this module on the working server without redeploying the whole ear file.
- The java classes (action handles and etc). Is it possible just to replace the bytecode of the classes that were changed?
- The jsp pages. I think they are launched indepently by the special jsp interpreter in glassfish. So this one definitely should have the possibility of the hot reload of a single changed page.
- I know I can perfectly replace the different parts of HTML design, such as css or js files, or image files. But what about the bytecode files described above?